# Pickle file works on one machine and doesn't work when opened on other

Tags: python, pickle

I work remotely on a cluster to which I connect via ssh. I run some tasks there and then I use pickle to save objects like that:

```
with open('tst.pkl','wb') as g:
  pickle.dump(pkl_pack, g)
```

Then when I am still on cluster I run python and type

```
with open('tst.pkl','rb') as f:
  pkl_pack = pickle.load(f)
```

and everything works great. Problem starts when I scp the .pkl file to my private computer

```
scp name@cluster:~/path/tst.pkl ./
```

then I run the same version of python as I was using on the cluster (python.3.5.2) and I execute the same command

```
with open('tst.pkl','rb') as f:
  pkl_pack = pickle.load(f)
```

but on my machine it produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "stringsource", line 15, in tenpy.linalg.np_conserved.Array.__setstate_cython__
TypeError: Expected tuple, got dict
```

and here I can't any longer work with the data.

Both on cluster and on my private computer I have the same versions of python as well as the library which I use (tenpy).

The same happen if I try to do it the other way around (save on my computer and restore on cluster), the error, however, is different:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '__pyx_unpickle_Array' on <module 'tenpy.linalg.np_conserved' from '/home/pwojcik/usr/lib/TeNPy/tenpy/linalg/np_conserved.py'>
```

Importing the library before loading pickle file doesn't help.

**EDIT**

The tenpy library allows one to check the version:

```
>>> print(tenpy.__full_version__)
b'v0.3.0\n' using python 3.5.2 (default, Aug  2 2018, 16:42:25) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] with numpy 1.15.0, scipy 1.1.0
```

and the GCC differes on my computer

```
>>> print(tenpy.__full_version__)
b'v0.3.0\n' using python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] with numpy 1.15.0, scipy 1.1.0
```

**EDIT II**

I have updated GCC version on cluster now I have

```
>>> print(tenpy.__full_version__)
b'v0.3.0\n' using python 3.5.2 (default, Aug  7 2018, 10:27:13) 
[GCC 5.4.0] with numpy 1.15.0, scipy 1.1.0
```

but pickle still produces the same error.

**EDIT III**

Pickle version: so as far as I understand the pickle have the same version as my python. The command

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep pickle
```

when executed it on my computer, I got

```
cloudpickle==0.5.3
pickleshare==0.7.4
```

and nothing on the cluster. So I installed the above packages on cluster

```
pip3 install cloudpickle 
pip3 install pickleshare
```

But the problem persists. I also did a tests of pickle with matplotlib.pyplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

data = plt.plot([0],[1])

with open('plot.pkl','wb') as g:
    pickle.dump(data,g)
```

A file 'plot.pkl' was prepared on cluster, scp-ied to my computer and there I was able to restore it using pickle without any errors.

Comment: @jpp Quote from question: "Both on cluster and on my private computer I have the same versions of python as well as the library which I use (tenpy)"

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Does the library have dependencies, e.g. `numpy`? You may also have to check the dependencies..

Comment: How did you check versions? Check which interpreter is really run. check for virtualenvs.

Comment: What's the version of Pickle on each computer? Run `pip3 freeze | grep pickle`.